# setState() called after dispose()

Tags: android, flutter, google, maps

Estou recebendo esse log em meu aplicativo flutter após integrar o google maps.

**Eu declarei isso logo no começo do código**

```
    CameraPosition _posicaoCamera = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(-23.562436, -46.655005),
      zoom: 18
  );
```

**E esse é meu setState que está recebendo o erro:**

```
    _adicionarListenerLocalizacao(){

    //-23.579934, -46.660715

    var geolocator = Geolocator();
    var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    geolocator.getPositionStream( locationOptions ).listen((Position position){

      setState(() {
        _posicaoCamera = CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
            zoom: 18
        );
        _movimentarCamera();
      });

    });

  }
```

Comment: Aonde esse setState está sendo chamado? O erro diz que essa linha está sendo chamada em um momento em que esse Widget não existe mais.

Comment: Sem problemas, vou escrever uma resposta para tentar ajudar com seu problema. Peço para você editar sua pergunta e incluir a função ```_adicionarListenerLocalizacao``` toda. Depender de links externos não é o objetivo deste site e corrigindo isso irá ajudar as próximas pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida .

Comment: Obrigaod pela dica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre pois você está chamando o código `setState` após o Widget em questão ter sido descartado.

Porque isso acontece? Você usou o método `listen` para ouvir uma Stream de posição do GPS. Sempre que houver uma variação de posição, o callback do setState será chamado, até mesmo quando este Widget não estiver mais na tela.

Para resolver isso, tem duas soluções:

- Salvar a Subscription em uma variável da classe e a cancelar quando esse Widget for destruído:

```
var subscription;
[...]
_adicionarListenerLocalizacao(){
    subscription = geolocator.getPositionStream( locationOptions ).listen((Position position){[...]});
    [...]
}
 @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Dessa forma você para de ouvir por variações de posição após esse método ter sido chamado.

Ou:

- Verificar se o widget existe antes de chamar o `setState`:

```
if (this.mounted){
 setState((){
      _posicaoCamera = CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
        zoom: 18
    );
    _movimentarCamera();
 });
}
```

Recomendo a primeira opção, pois deve-se parar de ouvir os eventos quando não se vai fazer mais uso deles.

O motivo pelo qual a primeira solução é a mais recomendada é para evitar que a sua app sofra de [Memory Leaks](https://www.devmedia.com.br/memory-leak-eliminando-vazamentos-de-memoria-em-java/28349), após uma certa quantidade de vezes que um usuário visita a mesma página, se a inscrições feitas não são canceladas as mesmas permanecem em memoria ocupando mais e mais espaço, até o momento em que o aparelho irá travar ou muito provavelmente o S.O irá forçar o fechamanto do aplicativo (crash) pois o mesmo está usando uma quantidade abusiva de recursos.
Sempre que possível dê preferência por usar os Widgets já presentes no Flutter para atualizar a sua app, como por exemplo o [Stream Builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkKEWHfy99Y) que irá gestir a sua stream, atualizar a interface quando necessário e automaticamente destruir a inscrição quando a mesma não for mais necessária.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção! 
Resposta concreta e que me ajudou muito entender o porque do erro!